# Use a different save method using async.eachSeries

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am using the [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) eachSeries function with mongoose that allows me to iterate through the array and save to the database with "boardDetails" and "newBoardDetails". The "saver" parameter will contain one of the two array items each time the object is saved to the database. My question is, for "newBoardDetails" I would not like to use the .save() function but I would like to use the .findByIdAndUpdate() function meaning that I would need to do something different on my second run through. How could I accomplish this?

```
var mongooseSave = [ boardDetails, newBoardDetails];

async.eachSeries(mongooseSave, function(saver, asyncdone) {
       saver.save(asyncdone);
    }, function(err) {
 if (err) return console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: pass a param and add a condition? if (param) { saver.save() } else { save. findByIdAndUpdate() }

Comment: Ok i'll try this thanks.